# Highstock chart - selecting '1 month' button in rangeSelector not changing button style as selected

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock chart with date values as x-axis and numbers corresponding to it on y-axis. rangeSelector buttons are 1 Week, 1 Month, 3 Months, All.

Problem is - When I am selecting 1 Week, 3 Months and All, its changing the style of button as selected but when I am clicking 1 Month, its style is not changing as selected and it gives impression that no button is selected. Though it changes in the chart and shows only 1 month of data.

My use case is same as this Highstock demo page. Here also, I see same issue on clicking 1m in the chart -  https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: I am not finding any issue https://imgur.com/a/MkHPd

Comment: Thanks @Deep3015 for the response. Can you check this one - https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line. I see the issue here.
Also I notice this issue is happening if I am in EST timezone. When I am changing my timezone to IST, its working fine.

Comment: Still I am not getting error. But you can use any option from https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global and try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7458

As an **workaround** you can change the definition of the first button from:

```
  {
    type: 'month',
    count: 1,
    text: '1m'
  }
```

to:

```
  {
    type: 'day',
    count: 30,
    text: '1m'
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/tqhsy2oa/

Another approach is to manually assign `highcharts-button-pressed` class to the SVG element using button's `click` event.

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons

Comment: Thanks Kamil Kulig for the response. I tried your solution and it worked. However I would like to add a note - this issue is with '1 Month' irrespective of its position among all other buttons and not with first range selector button as title of https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7458 says.